# System.currentTimeMillis() only updating every 128 seconds?

Tags: java, android

I have a loop in which I am checking seconds elapsed by doing `t-(long)(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000.0f)` where t is set to `t=(long)(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000.0f)` right before the loop. I find that `(long)(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000.0f)` is equal to t for the first 128 seconds. It then updates after another 128 seconds. I am doing this on a background thread. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System.currentTimeMillis() is a sufficiently large value that float cannot represent all integers around that range.

The fix is to simply use integer division by 1000.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to convert milis to second

```
long timeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
long timeSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timeMillis);
```

Comment: Holy cow, that is the long way to write `/1000`, to be sure.